# Drawing a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, drawing

I have to draw two horizontal lines in a cell, one in the vicinity of the edge at the top and the other near the button one. These two lines should be very pale yellow, that is the same color as the background view.
I must to create a subclass of UIView or a subclass of UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass a UIView, create custom DrawRect code inside it and load it as the cells background view. [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients) is an excellent tutorial on how to do this.